# How is energy really lost due to heating in charging a capacitor?

Tags: capacitance

Wanted to be sure, where is this understanding wrong?

If a capacitor is charged to a potential difference $V$, then $Q$ in the capacitor would be $CV$. Now if we assume the voltage of the power supply to be $V_{emf}$, then wouldn't the potential difference, $V_{emf} - V$ between the supply and the capacitor slowly decrease leading to the work done by the battery to store charge $Q$ on the capacitor be equal to the stored charge. I'll expand that a bit here.

The capacitor is charged until $V_{emf} = V$. $\quad$ At this point:  $\quad CV_{emf} = Q$

$$ E = \int_0^{CV_{emf}}{V_{emf} - V}\ dQ $$
$$ \quad = \int_0^{CV_{emf}}{V_{emf} - \frac QC}\ dQ $$
$$  \quad = {V_{emf}}^2 C - \frac{{V_{emf}}^2C^2}{2C} - 0 $$
$$ \quad = QV_{emf} - \frac12C{V_{emf}}^2 = QV_{emf} - \frac12QV_{emf}$$

Therefore the work done by the power supply is $\frac12QV_{emf}$

But this is apparently not the case as the work done by the power supply is $QV_{emf}$. Can someone explain?

Comment: The energy is converted into heat in the power supply which has a non-zero internal resistance and the wires which also have non-zero resistance. If you don't want to lose that energy, you can connect an inductor between the power supply and the capacitor. That's what switching power supplies do. The resulting loss can then be made very small (on the order of a few percent).

Comment: But how is that possible, as the capacitor only pulls charge to do work as per the potential difference... And in this process, if it loses energy, then the charge stored on the capacitor will be less than $\frac12QV$, as shown above.

Comment: Moving charge means that there is a current and since there is an inevitable resistance, that means $I^2R$ losses.

Comment: In that case, wouldn't the charge stored then be less than $\frac12QV$

Comment: No, the resistance has no influence on the charge (nothing can change charge conservation), it merely dissipates the excess energy.

Comment: Sorry, I meant energy. If there is a potential loss over the wire, then the energy reaching the capacitor would be less than 1/2QV, the V would have decreased isn't it?

Comment: The charge on the capacitor is given by the voltage and capacitance. How it got there makes no difference. The final voltage on the capacitor is the same as that of the voltage source, the resulting RC-circuit will simply take some time to charge the capacitor (in practice something like ten time constants is enough to make the final voltages indistinguishable).

Comment: Alright, so you mean to say that work done ultimately, overcoming resistances over the wire will be equal to $QV$. Seems like a bit of a coincidence that it is also equal to the work done across a constant P.D, a resistor for example.

Comment: I don't see any coincidence for any of this. Both charge and energy conservation hold and the rest is just a consequence.

Comment: It feels like a coincidence as the energy lost to resistance is exactly equal to 1/2QV while charging up a capacitor to 1/2QV.

Comment: In English the word "coincidence" means "a remarkable concurrence of events or circumstances without apparent causal connection". The causal connections here are given by charge and energy conservation, hence there is no "coincidence", it simply can't be any other way.

Comment: Alright. Its remarkable then.

Comment: At this point I will have to send you to english.stackexchange.com, I am afraid. No offense, by the way... what may be remarkable to you is kind of boring to us... some of us (like me) have known these things for most of our adult lives. At some point you are building up a tolerance for "remarkable". You will get there, too. Just give it some time.

Comment: Sure. No resistance. (pun intended)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is an $LC$ oscillator lossless, but $C V^2 / 2$ energy is lost to a capacitor connected to an ideal voltage source?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/209515/why-is-an-lc-oscillator-lossless-but-c-v2-2-energy-is-lost-to-a-capacito)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is resistance in the circuit and no inductance and assuming that, there is a resistor $R$, capacitor $C$ and voltage source $V_{\text{emf}}$ all in series, and the capacitor at time $t = 0$ is uncharged the following equation gives the variation of current with time

$I(t) = \dfrac {V_{\text{emf}}}{R}e^{-t/CR}$

The energy dissipated in the resistor while the capacitor is charging is

$\int^\infty _0 I^2R\; dt$

Doing the integration produces a the result $\frac 12 C V_{\text{emf}}^2$  which is independent of the value of the resistance.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the wire and the battery have certain resistance too. Do the calculation accounting for heat loss in the resistance. Add up the energy lost in the resistance and energy on the capacitor. You will find it to be $QV$